# JSON to a custom object hierarchy

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have some JSON, which consists of an array of objects that have an ID and name, as well as another object that gives the ID and name of the parent. It's essentially a folder structure, so a root folder will have sub folders, and they will also have sub folders etc.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 66880231, //unique
      "name": "root", //not unique
      "parent": null
    },
    {
      "id": 68102146,
      "name": "Dummy",
      "parent": {
        "id": 66880231,
        "name": "root"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 68509957,
      "name": "Test - Dummy",
      "parent": {
        "id": 68102146,
        "name": "Dummy"
      }
    },
    {
       "id": 68509998,
      "name": "Another Folder",
      "parent": {
        "id": 68102146,
        "name": "Dummy"
      }
    }
    
  ]
}
```

I am deseralizing this into an object called `ClioFolders`.

Next, I need to loop through each of the `ClioFolders` objects and put them into a new object called `AllClioFolders`, but instead of listing the parent, it will become a child object to the parent. I'm assuming `List` is the way to do this, but I am unsure.

This is the class for the custom object:

```
public class AllClioFolders
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public List<AllClioFolders> Children { get; set; }

}
```

In reality, I will have 18,000+ objects, and they're not necessarily in order. Each one will need to be added as a child object to it's parent.

The best way I can think to explain this, is to show what it would look like in JSON:

```
{
  "id": 66880231,
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 68102146,
      "name": "Dummy",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 68509957,
          "name": "Test - Dummy",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": 68509998,
          "name": "Another Folder",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that I cannot work out how to add the object to the relevant parent object. I'm almost certain LINQ needs to be used, but this extends past my c# knowledge. Any assistance would be appreciated greatly.

```
foreach(var folder in GetFolders.Data)
{
    if(folder.Parent == null)
    {
        //Root object
        AllClioFolders.Add(new AllClioFolders { Name = folder.Name, Id = folder.Id.ToString() });
    }
    else
    {
        //Child Object
        //Add this object to the correct parent object
        // AllClioFolders.Add(????);
    }
            
}
```

**Update:**
I suspect something like this should work, but it would only add to the top level object's child object, it needs to be able to look through ALL child objects.

```
var obj = AllClioFolders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == folder.Parent.ToString());
if (obj != null) obj.Children.Add(new AllClioFolders { Name = folder.Name, Id = folder.Id.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this approach and it's work well.
Group all *children* by *parent id* and populate recursively all `children` for each `parent` :

1 - classes :
Note that,I have changed the type of `Id` in `AllClioFolders` to `Int`

```
public  class RootObject
{
    public List<ClioFolder> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClioFolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class AllClioFolders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<AllClioFolders> Children { get; set; }

}
```

2 - *Json*

```
string json = @"{
                  'data': [
                    {
                      'id': 66880231,
                      'name': 'root',
                      'parent': null
                    },
                    {
                      'id': 68102146,
                      'name': 'Dummy',
                      'parent': {
                        'id': 66880231,
                        'name': 'root'
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      'id': 68509957,
                      'name': 'Test - Dummy',
                      'parent': {
                        'id': 68102146,
                        'name': 'Dummy'
                      }
                    },
                    {
                       'id': 68509998,
                      'name': 'Another Folder',
                      'parent': {
                        'id': 68102146,
                        'name': 'Dummy'
                      }
                    }

                  ]
                }";
```

3 - json De-Serialization, construction of parent and grouping children by parent id:

```
List<ClioFolder> allClios = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)?.Data;

//get parent
ClioFolder clioFolder = allClios.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Parent == null);
AllClioFolders allClioParent = new AllClioFolders
{
    Id = clioFolder.Id,
    Name = clioFolder.Name,
    Children = new List<AllClioFolders>()
};

// group by parent id
Dictionary<int, List<ClioFolder>> groupedChilds = allClios
    .Where(c => c.Parent != null)
    .GroupBy(c => c.Parent.Id)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
    
AddChildrenRecursively(groupedChilds, allClioParent);

string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allClioParent);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

4 - Implementation of the method

```
static void AddChildrenRecursively(Dictionary<int, List<ClioFolder>> groupeChilds, AllClioFolders allClioParent)
{
    if (groupeChilds.ContainsKey(allClioParent.Id))
    {
        allClioParent.Children = groupeChilds[allClioParent.Id].Select(x => new AllClioFolders { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList();

        foreach (AllClioFolders childOfChild in allClioParent.Children)
        {
            AddChildrenRecursively(groupeChilds, childOfChild);
        }
    }
}
```

**Resut**

```
{
   "Id":66880231,
   "Name":"root",
   "Children":[
      {
         "Id":68102146,
         "Name":"Dummy",
         "Children":[
            {
               "Id":68509957,
               "Name":"Test - Dummy",
               "Children":null
            },
            {
               "Id":68509998,
               "Name":"Another Folder",
               "Children":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Very grateful. This is the solution I've gone with. I just need to add the JSON for the files to this and around 7 hours of struggling with this is finally over!

Comment: Quick question, There is another object along side "Data" called "Meta" that contains the paging data. I added the classes for this, but the deserialization is set to Data, If I remove this, it breaks.

Comment: @user2924019 can you share a sample for better understanding :). if you use the `RootObject` that i added an answer i think will work if you don't add the Meta to this class.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is depends.
Depends on what you want to obtain.

What you show in your example json is nothing else than a tree structure.

You have the first json but reversed (you have pointers to the parent instead the having them to the children) cause parent is only one.

So if you want to reproduce the tree structure in the object you were close enough, you would just have to use recursion.

```
AllClioFolders rootClioFolder;
List<AllClioFolders> orphans;
foreach(var folder in GetFolders.Data)
{
  AllClioFolders currentFolder=new AllClioFolders { Name = folder.Name, Id = folder.Id.ToString() };
    if(folder.Parent == null)
    {
        //Root object
        rootClioFolder=currentFolder;
    }
    else
    {
         AllClioFolders parentFolder=findParent(currentFolder.Id,rootClioFolder);
        if (parentFolder!=null){
            parentFolder.Children.Add(currentFolder);
        }else{
            orphans.Add(currentFolder)
        }
    }
            
}


function AllClioFolders findParent(string Id,AllClioFolders treeFolder){
    AllClioFolders resultFolder=null;
    if (currentFolder.Id==Id){
        resultFolder=treeFolder;
    }else{
        foreach (AllClioFolders children in treeFolder.Children){
              resultFolder=findParent(Id,children);
              if (resultFolder!=null) break;
        }
    }
    return resultFolder;
}
```

Notes:

- Code is not tested, just explaining logic, please fix it if broken.
- Items in json can be not in order but you must have always childrens after parents.
- You can't use linq to orderBy cause by your example you have parents who have numeric Id both higher and lower than childrens.
- If you have them in wrong order (parents after childrens) you could solve it doing multiple foreach until all orphans have found their Parents.

**BUT**, I would suggest to change the class and just use a `Dictionary<string,AllClioFolders>` where the Id is the key, so you can simply access directly by id and you can iterate.

**EDIT**: I noticed I read wrong and Ids are incremental, if that is the case then you just need to do `GetFolders.Data.OrderBy(function (folder) folder.Id)`

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to put it together now.